# Create new variables by group in long form data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

The data looks like this:

```
id<-c(35,35,35,35,35,35,470,470,470,470,470,133,133,133,133,133,133)
age<-c(19,21,24,25,26,29,22,29,31,39,42,27,32,35,39,40,41)
work<-c('pt','ft','pt','none','none','none','pt','ft','pt','pt','ft','ft','ft','pt','ft','none','pt')

df<-data.frame(id,age,work)
```

I would like to create a new variable called age1ft, which is the age when that person (id) first had a full time (ft) job.

So the end product should look something like

```
   id age work age1ft
1   35  19   pt     21
2   35  21   ft     21
3   35  24   pt     21
4   35  25 none     21
5   35  26 none     21
6   35  29 none     21
7  470  22   pt     29
8  470  29   ft     29
9  470  31   pt     29
10 470  39   pt     29
11 470  42   ft     29
12 133  27   ft     27
13 133  32   ft     27
14 133  35   pt     27
15 133  39   ft     27
16 133  40 none     27
17 133  41   pt     27
```

I tried this:

```
df2<-df %>% 
  group_by(id,work) %>% 
  mutate(age1ft=ifelse(work=='ft',which.min(age),NA))
```

That didn't work. I guess there must be data.table options but I am more familiar with dplyr.

Answer (score 1):

We `arrange` the rows by 'id' and 'age', then with a grouping by 'id', get the position of the first 'ft' with `match`, use that index to subset the 'age'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(id, age) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(age1ft = age[match('ft', work)])
```

---

Or after grouping by 'id', subset the 'age' with a logical expression, get the `min` (or for the largest use `max`)

```
df %>% 
    group_by(id) %>%
     mutate(age1ft = min(age[work == 'ft']))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it in data.table, which I think is really intuitive.

```
setDT(df)
df[df[work == 'ft', .(age1ft = min(age)), id], on = .(id), age1ft := i.age1ft]
```

I create a new, smaller table that's got the id variable and the year of first full time work and then I merge them. Has the added benefit of being really fast.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP requires the first year of full time employment to be  appended to *all* rows of an `id`.

For the sake of completeness, here is another data.table version which updates `df` *by reference*, i.e., without copying the whole data object.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, age1ft := min(age[work == "ft"]), by = id]

df[]
```

> ```
>      id age work age1ft
>  1:  35  19   pt     21
>  2:  35  21   ft     21
>  3:  35  24   pt     21
>  4:  35  25 none     21
>  5:  35  26 none     21
>  6:  35  29 none     21
>  7: 470  22   pt     29
>  8: 470  29   ft     29
>  9: 470  31   pt     29
> 10: 470  39   pt     29
> 11: 470  42   ft     29
> 12: 133  27   ft     27
> 13: 133  32   ft     27
> 14: 133  35   pt     27
> 15: 133  39   ft     27
> 16: 133  40 none     27
> 17: 133  41   pt     27
> ```